# Bash script adds a  special character to mkdir names?

Tags: bash, git-bash

txt with the following contents:

```
.workingDocuments
images
.database
```

I run a bash script (codespaces git bash shell):

```
while read -r line; do 
  mkdir "$line"
done < folders.txt
```

The script creates the folders but adds a special character  at the end of each folder?

```
.database
.workingDocuments
images
```

this will be part of a student activity so I specifically want to use a while loop with mkdir but I don't want the special character.

I have same issue with a similar script and file to create files using `touch`

Comment: Could be Windows line endings. Check out [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF)](/q/2613800/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea I added echo $line and there is no special character it is occuring in the mkdir? I would assuem if it was a line ending issue it would also show in the echo?

Comment: Your `folders.txt` file probably has Windows line endings (CR-LF).  `echo $line` won't show them (and doesn't work in general).  Use `declare -p line` instead.

Comment: This character must therefore be already present in folders.txt. Have a look at this file on a hexadecimal level, i.e. `xxd folders.txt`.

Comment: Running `cat -v folders.txt` should reveal the CR characters as `^M` at the end of each line.